# Combine array of maps into single map in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a function similar to the collect_list or collect_set to aggregate a column of maps into a single map in a (grouped) pyspark dataframe? For example, this function might have the following behavior:

```
>>>df.show()

+--+---------------------------------+
|id|                             map |
+--+---------------------------------+
| 1|                    Map(k1 -> v1)|
| 1|                    Map(k2 -> v2)|
| 1|                    Map(k3 -> v3)|
| 2|                    Map(k5 -> v5)|
| 3|                    Map(k6 -> v6)|
| 3|                    Map(k7 -> v7)|
+--+---------------------------------+

>>>df.groupBy('id').agg(collect_map('map')).show()

+--+----------------------------------+
|id|                 collect_map(map) |
+--+----------------------------------+
| 1| Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2, k3 -> v3)|
| 2|                     Map(k5 -> v5)|
| 3|           Map(k6 -> v6, k7 -> v7)|
+--+----------------------------------+
```

It probably wouldn't be too difficult to produce the desired result using one of the other collect_ aggregations and a udf, but it seems like something like this should already exist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's map_concat in the pyspark version >= 2.4

Comment: I have tried using the map_concat as the aggregator and I get this error : "expression '`test2`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function." test2 is the name of the column that contains the maps.

Answer (score 10):

I know it is probably poor form to provide an answer to your own question before others have had a chance to answer, but in case someone is looking for a udf based version, here is one possible answer.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,collect_list
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType,StringType

combineMap=udf(lambda maps: {key:f[key] for f in maps for key in f},
               MapType(StringType(),StringType()))

df.groupBy('id')\
  .agg(collect_list('map')\
  .alias('maps'))\
  .select('id',combineMap('maps').alias('combined_map')).show()
```

Answer (score 9):

The suggested solution with concat_map deosn't work and this solution doesn't use UDFs.
For spark>=2.4

```
(df
.groupBy(f.col('id'))
.agg(f.collect_list(f.col('map')).alias('maps'), 
.select('id',
        f.expr('aggregate(slice(maps, 2, size(maps)), maps[0], (acc, element) -> map_concat(acc, element))').alias('mapsConcatenated')
        )
)
```

collect_list ignores the null values so no need to worry about them when using map_concat in aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Using aggregate() with default map() of <string,string> datatype.

```
val df = Seq(
    
(1,"k1","v1"),
(1,"k2","v2"),
(1,"k3","v3"),
(2,"k5","v5"),
(3,"k6","v6"),
(3,"k7","v7")
    ).toDF("id","k","v")

df.show()

+---+----------+
|id |m         |
+---+----------+
|1  |{k1 -> v1}|
|1  |{k2 -> v2}|
|1  |{k3 -> v3}|
|2  |{k5 -> v5}|
|3  |{k6 -> v6}|
|3  |{k7 -> v7}|
+---+----------+

df.createOrReplaceTempView("id_map")

spark.sql("""
with t1 ( select *, map(k,v) m from id_map ),
     t2  (select id, collect_list(m) m1  from t1 group by id )
  select id, aggregate(m1, cast(map() as map<string,string>), (acc,x) -> map_concat(acc,x)) m2 from t2   
""").show(false)

+---+------------------------------+
|id |m2                            |
+---+------------------------------+
|1  |{k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2, k3 -> v3}|
|2  |{k5 -> v5}                    |
|3  |{k6 -> v6, k7 -> v7}          |
+---+------------------------------+
```

or using the struct() and map_from_entries()

```
spark.sql("""
with t1 ( select *, struct(k,v) m from id_map ),
     t2  (select id, collect_list(m) m1  from t1 group by id )
  select id, map_from_entries(m1) m2 from t2   
""").show(false)

+---+------------------------------+
|id |m2                            |
+---+------------------------------+
|1  |{k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2, k3 -> v3}|
|2  |{k5 -> v5}                    |
|3  |{k6 -> v6, k7 -> v7}          |
+---+------------------------------+
```